# Quick CSS query

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a shorter way of writing this?

```
.form1 input[group="write"], .form1 select[group="write"], .form1 textarea[group="write"] { display: none; }
```

the `group` is just an attribute i use to group inputs.

ideally Id like

```
.form1 (input|select|textarea)[group="write"] { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you're not using `class` to group your form elements instead of a custom attribute like `group`, but anyway, I suppose this catch-all rule will do:

```
.form1 [group="write"] { display: none; }
```

If you need to explicitly match `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements only, there's no shorter way in CSS3 than what you have.

Comment: hahaha! i never thought of just dropping out the tags and using just the [group="write"]... doh! thanks!

Comment: Bear in mind this affects *everything* with `group="write"`, slightly different than the original CSS. But I agree with Boltclock 100%, why not use classes? I suppose you've got your reasons, but it's worth reconsidering them.

Comment: It will hide all elements with attribute `group="write"`, how about to hide only listed ones?

Comment: im using group because i have a form with group="write" and group="read" on parts of the form that i want visible when the form is in edit mode or read mode which changes without re-posting the form back to the server. :)

Comment: If you must use a custom attribute, consider calling it `data-group` to comply with HTML5 naming conventions.

Comment: @Christian — That doesn't explain why you are using a made up markup language instead of HTML (i.e. why you aren't using the class attribute).

Comment: using group instead of class was easier back before html5 to show and hide elements of a form depending on the mode. Now it's easy to addClass or removeClass so i suppose i will change it.